# How can we calculate $g$ force in this maneuver?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, aerodynamics, aircraft

> How can we calculate $g$ force in this maneuver?

We are not dealing with conventional maneuvers like level turn or loop so  what equation used to calculate g force in this maneuver?

[image]

What about other special maneuvers? Which equation used for them?

Comment: Take a simple barrel-roll. The pilot has complete control over the g-force, by pushing or pulling the stick. There are videos of people pouring coffee all during a barrel-roll. They do this by starting the maneuver in a climb, then curve downward over the top, and end up in a descent. Maneuvers are complicated.

Answer (score 2):

If the forward component of velocity does not change, that leaves only gravity and a centripetal force in all cases.

Comment: can you show the forward component of velocity and centripetal force in that case on a picture?

Comment: On a picture, you can only show 2D components of 3D vectors. Centripetal forces would  be toward the center of curvature of curved motion.